# Retry Policy for Eventbridge Scheduler in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, scheduler, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to implement Retry Policy into CloudFormation for Event Bridge Scheduler. According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-scheduler-schedule-retrypolicy.html), it seems possible, however, when I try to deploy it that way, I get an error

```
Properties validation failed for resource Scheduler with message: #: extraneous key [RetryPolicy] is not permitted
```

I have tried to put the Retry Policy block directly into `Properties`:

```
  SchedulerSchedule:
    Type: AWS::Scheduler::Schedule
    Properties:
      RetryPolicy:
         MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 3600
         MaximumRetryAttempts: 3
     ...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RetryPolicy` needs to be part of a [`Target`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-scheduler-schedule-target.html), not a top level property of the `Schedule` itself.

```
MyFirstSchedule:
  Type: AWS::Scheduler::Schedule
  Properties:
    ...
    Target:
      ...
      RetryPolicy:
        MaximumEventAgeInSeconds: 3600
        MaximumRetryAttempts: 3
```